# Kommen or gehen?

Tags: sentence-structure

I would like to ask:

> **How do we go from here to Bach street?**

for example from someone in the street. Thus, I asked:

> **Wie gehen wir von hier zur Bachstraße?**

But, I was told that I should ask instead:

> **Wie kommen wir von hier zur Bachstraße?**
> Why is it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do we *go* from here *to* Bach street?
>
> (Wie *gehen* wir von hier *zur* Bachstraße?)

The problem is that already this english sentence is not idiomatic. Instead of

- *to go to* → *gehen / laufen zu*

it is more idiomatic to use

- *to get to* → *kommen / gelangen zu*

The example sentence becomes

> How do we *get* from here *to* Bach street?
>
> (Wie *kommen / gelangen* wir von hier *zur* Bachstraße?)

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer.

Comment: @Novice, you are welcome.

Comment: Kann man die Proposition "an" in solcher Frage anstatt "zu" nützen? Z.B. in "wie komme ich von hier an den Strand?"?

Comment: @sermonionx Sounds good to me. Probably best when there is a line to approach to ("an die Küste, den Strand, den Stadtrand"). With a "point destination" it's "zu" ("wie komme ich zum Bahnhof"); if you can enter something, it can be "in" ("wie komme ich in den Bahnhof " (you don't find the entrance), "in die Stadt, ins Gebäude" etc); with city names it's "nach" ("wie komme ich von hier am besten nach Berlin").

Comment: Good answer. "Wie gehen wir" could be used to emphasize that we will be walking.